# Bootstrap grid system: is this code correct?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'd like to ask can this code be correct from Bootstrap point of view? I expect the answer is yes. The question is about additional tag in between row and col(s).

```
<div class="row">
<something>
<div class="col-sm-6">
a
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
b
</div>
</something>
</div>
```

P.S. `<something>` has no css styles and that's a directive from AngularJS.

Comment: If it's just a div...it's no problem..it'll be 100% wide. It depends on what the element actually is.

Comment: Yes, This code is correct form bootstrap point of view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)..

> Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be
>   immediate children of rows.

The Bootstrap `row` has a negative margin to compensate for column padding. `<something>` doesn't specifically cause a problem in your example, but it's incorrect from a Bootstrap standpoint.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong here, but there are better practices on using bootstrap.

Just take care of minus margins and clearfix, check if the style flow its ok.

By the way, you can use "comment directive" if u need to use that something tag just for angularJs directive.

Answer (score 1):

In that code, the `something` tag will simply be given the entire 12 column width of the `row` div. The internal elements will then be split into the relevant grids as long as there is nothing on the something tag which would interfere.

I think this should work fine, but as a sidenote I would normally write this as

```
<something>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
a
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
b
</div>
</div>
</something>
```

That way then gives you the option to add more rows etc into the `something` section easily if needed, and just aids readability in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `row` basically has the same purpose as `col-md-12`, but `row` will give you a margin of -15px to both left and right. To avoid a horizontal scroll-bar you can wrap the whole thing in a div with the class `container`.

Answer (score 0):

looks good to me but i think according to your "something" element it can vary